# ADB does not see my Android device (Spectrum II)

Tags: android, adb

This is not a duplicate post.  I have searched and read extensively and none of the solutions I've come across have been successful.

Win 7 64 bit
LG Spectrum II running build VS93022A (Android 4.1.2)
Eclipse version...from the SDK as downloaded on 09/07/13...so, the latest

I did install the actual vendor drivers for my device, not just using the default from Windows that kick in when you first connect it.  I can view the device and SD card contents via windows explorer.  It is by any criteria clearly and correctly connected to my computer.

Allow USB debugging is checked on the device.  The USB connection mode is "Media sync (MTP)".

Used "adb devices" from command line and it lists no devices.

Restarted everything multiple times.

The selected minimum Android version for the project is Gingerbread.  My device, as stated above, is running the absolute most recent Android build available (updated itself two nights ago, actually).

The device still does not show up.  Any ideas?

---

edit: The advice found here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

cannot be follow because it is incorrect.  In Device Manager, there is no entry under Portable Devices (where my phone appears) which reads "Android Composite ADB Interface."

On a side note, is all of the Android developer documentation this terrible?

Comment: In windows device management, do you see the name of your phone? If not, your drivers are the wrong one.

Comment: do you get the debug icon in your notification bar when your device is plugged in? also, if `adb devices` does not list your device then your problem really has nothing to do with eclipse...

Comment: In "Device Manager," yes, my phone does appear underneath "Portable Devices", as "LGE Android MTP Device".

What does the debug icon look like?  There is a USB icon.

Comment: I also attempted "allow mock locations" but that does nothing.

Comment: Do you know your device's IP address, for example 192.168.0.3? Try to run this command "abd connect 192.168.0.3" and later "adb devices" to see whether it is connected or not (make sure USB debugging is set on)

Comment: Try to see the driver for LG in http://junefabrics.com/android/driver.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my device. To solve it I plugged it in with usb debugging unchecked then checked it. A notification came up on the phone saying "allow this computers RSA?" or something similar and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something I just came across after I had installed iTunes on my PC (previously I was able to debug over USB, then it stopped working).  Go to Services and stop "Apple Mobile Device Service" as it interferes with the USB for Android debugging.